# STS(Spring Tool Suite) not responding

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

My STS stops responding within few minutes after the Workspace is built. What might be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Are you using Maven? Sometimes I had issues reaching dependencies and STS was blocking every task during waiting for response. Please post your STS version.

Comment: yes. I am using maven 3.3.3 and STS 3.7.1.
And only since yesterday morning i am facing this problem, before that it was working fine. I tried using  32 bit as well 64 bit versions of STS. Both of them stopped responding in few minutes.

Comment: Ok, what has changed since yesterday morning?

Comment: After the STS starts, on the very first click on the screen it freezes. Then I have to close it with the help of Task manager. I can not figure out how this problem popped out from nowhere.

Comment: No, I mean what exactly has changed on your system. Did you installed some programs which are running in the background (and are constantly decreasing your available memory)? Or did your hardware change?

Comment: I'm experiencing same issue since today, I've killed process at least 5 times then retried but nothing...
Xmx 2048

Comment: I too have the same issue and it started behaving like after upgrading few plugins. Not sure if there is some issue due to upgraded plugins. May i know if there is any way to revert my plugin installations, please help me

Answer (score 2):

I removed below property from STS.init, now it is working fine for me.

--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the memory it's allowed to use in the STS.ini file

```
C0243321@IKHCPKISBN0084S /cygdrive/c/opensource/sts-bundle/sts-3.6.4.RELEASE
$ cat STS.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any antivirus then turn off when using STS.
Its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can open file STS.ini and add

openFile

-C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe